# I want to run a Linux based device application without hardware

Tags: linux, usb, emulation

Is there any simulation environment that allows to run and test Linux based USB device application on host machine running Linux?

Also same thing for Linux based USB host side applications where one can run and test Linux based host applications with physical/virtual USB devices.

Regards,
Mooni

Comment: You can't just copy what would be on the USB device to a bootable image and use something like QEMU? Perhaps I'm not fully understanding your question .. but I have great success with QEMU or Simics (Simics when I really heed debugging and its absent in the OS).

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking if it's possible to use a general purpose PC to simulate a USB device?  If so, no, the hardware on, say, your motherboard is not physically capable (in almost all cases) of emulating a USB client device.

Comment: Firstly it is not possible to simulate my custom USB device in PC System emulation mode.
Secondly QEMU does not provide emulation for any platform with USB function controller which means it is not possible even in non PC emulation of QEMU.